# Vue.js render new data from API call

Tags: vue.js, fetch, render

I am making a weather app written in Vue.js, which fetches weather data periodically, but I have an issue rendering new data after the initial API call.

The empty data array is declared in the data, and a timer is used to fetch new data, as such:

```
      data() {
        return {
          weatherData: [],
          timer: '',
    };
  },
```

I have declared the data fetching in methods, as such:

```
methods: {
    async fetchWeatherData() {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5002/timeseries");
      const data = await response.json();
      if (response.ok) {
        console.log("Data fetched sucssefully!");
      }
      return data;
    },
```

And when the app loads, the fetchWeatherData and setInterval is initiated:

```
  async created() {
     this.weatherData = await this.fetchWeatherData();
     setInterval(() => this.timer = this.fetchWeatherData(), 10000)

  },
```

The problem is that the new data is not rendered to the DOM, although new data is fetched successfully.

What would be the best step to ensure that the new data is rendered correctly upon successfull fetch?

-HK

Comment: You should check that the return value of the method `fetchWeatherData` is actually an Array.

Comment: I checked whether it is an array or not, and indeed it is an Array.

Comment: Well, then Vue will re-render the template as soon as you assign this array to `weatherData`

Comment: Alright, I figured out what is wrong. I am manipulating the data before it is rendered, i.e. I have a function that finds the highest and lowest temperatures for a given day. Basically, this function takes the weatherData-array and a day of interest as arguments and returns the max/min temperatures of the day. This function is not called upon new data from the API... What would be the best approach to call the function on new data?

Comment: Instead of `() => this.timer = this.fetchWeatherData()` try `() => this.weatherData = this.fetchWeatherData()`

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either. I added a new empty array that is used to store the max/min temperatures in the component data, as I thought that would trigger reactivity of this max/min data, however, with no luck. At this point, I am tempted to set nodemon to relaunch the server, since I'd only be needing to fetch new data every 12 hours or so...

Comment: If you can reproduce the issue on CodeSandbox - we will be able to assist you better.

Comment: The problem was that the setIntarval was not async, and in each iteration I returned a promise, not the weateherData. This solution was posted by James Thomson over at the Vue Forum. I really appreciate you taking time to help me, tho! :) Take care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, as posted by [James Thomson](https://forum.vuejs.org/u/JamesThomson) over at the Vue forum, was to set the setInterval to async, since the fetch method also is async. See the full answer [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/render-new-data-from-api-call/122322/3).

Answer (score 1):

In the component (or any container) where you render the weather data, add a key (like :key="renderWeatherKey"). Add renderWeatherKey to component data.

```
data() {
        return {
          weatherData: [],
          timer: '',
          renderWeatherKey: 0
    };
  },
```

In the method fetchWeatherData(), inside 'if' condition, add this.renderWeatherKey++ :

```
async fetchWeatherData() {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5002/timeseries");
      const data = await response.json();
      if (response.ok) {
        console.log("Data fetched sucssefully!");
        this.renderWeatherKey++
      }
      return data;
    },
```

You can force the re rendered with that.

Comment: This is quite an elegant suggestion, but unfortunately this did not solve my problem

Comment: @Hans-KristianNorumEidesen even with the :key="renderWeatherKey" in your component container? Strange, maybe because you need to wait for data ( const data = await response.json()) instead of response.ok ??

Comment: Yes, I had to wait for the data in n-th iteration (in the setInterval). Setting await in the setInterval-line was what solved the issue. Just FYI, your solution did work, but only with await was set properly. Again, I really found your suggestion to be quite beautiful :)